# Distribute React Native components for iOS via XCFramework

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I have a bunch of React Native UI components that live in a dedicated GitHub repository. I want to distributed them via an XCFramework.

Searching online, I see many SO questions or blog posts about adding an XCFramework to an RN module. However, what I want to do is sort of the opposite. I want to make an RN module into an XCFramework.

I'd appreciate any tip or resource. Thanks!

*Apologies if I misused the terms "module" and "component". I'm an RN noob.*